# Imposing a condition into frequency table. (Modifying th code)

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I modify the below code to just showing the levels with frequency > 10%. In my real data set, the categorical variable has 35 levels and for better visualization, I am not bring all the levels into the plot. 2- How can I manage the size of plot, since some levels have very high frequencies and some are very low.
The data set is from car package.

```
table_ <- ggplot(States, aes(region ,fill=region))
table_ <- table_ + geom_bar() 
table_ <- table_ + theme(legend.position="none")
table_ <- table_ + coord_flip()
table_ <- table_ + geom_text(aes(y = (..count..),label = ifelse((..count..)==0,"",scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)))), 
                                                                                                             stat="count",colour="black",vjust=1.0,size=4)
```

Comment: @ mtoto, thanks for your reply. I got this error: Error in quantile.default(States$region, 0.1) : factors are not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first create a `levels` vector of the variables you want on your x-axis:

```
# Extract the factor levels with > 0.1 relative frequencies
levels <- names(which(summary(States$region)/sum(summary(States$region)) >0.1))

# If you just want for example the top ten variables (question 2)
levels <- names(sort(summary(States$region),decreasing=TRUE)[1:10])
```

Then you can use it define the `limit`  argument of `scale_x_discrete`:

```
table_ + ... + scale_x_discrete(limit = levels)
```

Comment: @ mtoto, Thanks for your solution, but What I want is having the percentage based on whole data set, if I remove some levels from the data set, the percentage would be different. What I want is just dropping some levels from the plot and showing the other levels with the real percentage.

Comment: @shoorideh  then perhaps `scale_x_discrete(limit = levels)` ?

Comment: @ mtoto, exactly, great

Comment: @ mtoto, do you also have any idea regarding the second question?

Comment: @ mtoto, I tired scale_x_discrete(limit = levels) , however the percentages still are not based on all observation! Do you have another suggestion regarding fixing this issue?